# Send updates from a PHP web app to an Android App without calling POST or GET requests from Android Side

Tags: php, android, webhooks

I don't know if it has already been answered or not. But here is my case:

I have a PHP web app that interacts with TELNYX API (An API to send and receive messages), when someone sends me a message, the TELNYX API sends a webhook to my PHP web app where I can see who sent me the message and what's the content in there.

Now what I want is to send that data(webhook's result) from the PHP web app to my Android Application. Now is there any way that I can continuously listen to the server and whenever the server receives the webhook, it forwards those hooks to my android app?

Comment: you need stream, you should use websockets or never release the response

Comment: Push notifications? Depends if it's supposed to alert the user, or do something else.